# Nginx shows requests to endpoints, not in my API, And unknown requests

Tags: django, docker, nginx

Nginx works in Docker compose with Django, react, postgress containers
Nginx shows requests for PHP, testPHP endpoints with status code 200

```bash
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:21 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin5.2/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:21 +0000] "GET /2phpmyadmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:21 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/wp-pma-mod/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:21 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin4/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:22 +0000] "GET /mysql/sqlmanager/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:22 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2016/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:22 +0000] "GET /db/myadmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:22 +0000] "GET /sql/websql/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:22 +0000] "GET /php-my-admin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:23 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin-5.3.0-all-languages/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:23 +0000] "GET /shopdb/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:23 +0000] "GET /administrator/db/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:23 +0000] "GET /sql/php-myadmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:23 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2014/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:24 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin-5.1.2/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:24 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:24 +0000] "GET /db/db-admin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:24 +0000] "GET /sql/phpmyadmin5/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:24 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin-3/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:25 +0000] "GET /administrator/phpMyAdmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:25 +0000] "GET /admin/phpMyAdmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:25 +0000] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/phpMyAdmin/index.php%3Flang%3Den HTTP/1.1" 200 2313 "http://147.182.131.129/admin/phpMyAdmin/index.php?lang=en" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:25 +0000] "GET /db/webdb/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:25 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2015/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:26 +0000] "GET /mysql/admin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:26 +0000] "GET /sql/phpmanager/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:26 +0000] "GET /administrator/db/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:26 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2020/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:26 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin5/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:27 +0000] "GET /phpmy/192.1index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:27 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin5.2/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:27 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2022/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:27 +0000] "GET /sql/sql-admin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:27 +0000] "GET /sql/sqlweb/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:28 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2015/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:28 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin-4.9.7/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:28 +0000] "GET /2phpmyadmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:28 +0000] "GET /database/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:28 +0000] "GET /db/phpMyAdmin3/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:29 +0000] "GET /administratorindex.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:29 +0000] "GET /sql/phpmanager/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:29 +0000] "GET /sql/phpmanager/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:29 +0000] "GET /sql/sqlweb/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:29 +0000] "GET /db/myadmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:30 +0000] "GET /administrator/web/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:30 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/wp-pma-mod/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:30 +0000] "GET /admin/pma/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:31 +0000] "GET /_phpmyadmin_/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:31 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2019/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:31 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2016/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:31 +0000] "GET /db/phpMyAdmin-5/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:31 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-all-languages/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:32 +0000] "GET /db/phpMyAdmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:32 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2012/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:32 +0000] "GET /php-myadmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:32 +0000] "GET /db/phpMyAdmin-5/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:33 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:33 +0000] "GET /admin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    37.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:34 +0000] "GET /db/phpMyAdmin-5/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:34 +0000] "GET /sql/sql-admin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:34 +0000] "GET /administrator/PMA/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:34 +0000] "GET /admin/sqladmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:35 +0000] "GET /mysql/web/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:35 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:35 +0000] "GET /sql/phpmy-admin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:35 +0000] "GET /sql/phpMyAdmin2/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:36 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2021/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:36 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2019/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:36 +0000] "GET /db/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:36 +0000] "GET /dbadmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:36 +0000] "GET /sql/sqladmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:37 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin-latest-english/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:37 +0000] "GET /mysql/mysqlmanager/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:37 +0000] "GET /db/phpmyadmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:37 +0000] "GET /administrator/db/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:37 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin2012/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:38 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin4/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:38 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:38 +0000] "GET /phpMyAdmin-5.1.1/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:38 +0000] "GET /db/phpmyadmin3/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:38 +0000] "GET /dbadmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    1.171.112.23 - - [27/Nov/2022:09:37:39 +0000] "GET /sql/phpmanager/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
    197.60.121.41 - - [2
```

unknown requests

```bash
192.155.90.118 - - [28/Nov/2022:02:54:21 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x85\x01\x00\x00\x81\x03\x03>\x99\xEF\xEF\xEB\xEC\xC3\x80\x02\xA9\xD7e\xEC\xE1)\xEDS\xA9\xCE\xB63\x92P\xE2\xF9db\x02{\x1F\xDF\xA2\x00\x00 \xC0/\xC00\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA8\xCC\xA9\xC0\x13\xC0\x09\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
51.79.29.48 - - [28/Nov/2022:02:54:24 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "-"
51.79.29.48 - - [28/Nov/2022:02:54:24 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "-"
185.254.196.223 - - [28/Nov/2022:02:55:11 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "-"
185.254.196.223 - - [28/Nov/2022:02:55:11 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.105.89.161 - - [28/Nov/2022:03:20:23 +0000] "\xBA\xABd\xA1EZC\xDBM\x87\xEE^\xFD\xBF\x159 X\xD4>\x12\x98\xC4<\xE0\x13\xCF\x00\xAC\xA09\xD7\x90#8~\x8C\xDE\x9DReF\xBF%1Q\xE0\x9D\x06&g\xBB\x82\x95\x19\xED\x07\x14\x19ZP\x80+\x94e\xC3\xE6\x85\x06\xA4\x99\x8B\x19l\x01\xEA\x88Y\x91\x16\x95\xC4\xC8\x0EH\x02\xC7\x93g\xC14FW\x05|\xFB\xF3T\xB8\xFD\xCB\xBB)\xE3\xCE\xDD\xCD7\x9E\xEFP\x8C\xA4[V\xFD\x98\xC9l\x82\xF5\xE4\xC1d\x87X\xF7\x9B\xBF\xE8q\x12\x99&\xDB,\xF5\x87\xD7\xA8\x97j;\xE3\xEA\xA7\xB4\xB0\x02\xAD\x8DE\x9B\xAAB\x80\x0E)\xA9\xE9\xAF}\x18\x8E\xB8\x1E\x99\x04\xEF\xA8\x8C\xE8\x04\xE2\xD3\xED)1\x91\xC1\x8F\x88\x8C\x81\xF0\xDB\xA5\x88\x95H\x9BZ\xAB\xCE\xBF\xF4E%P*\x88KFY6\x9E\xE7::j\xD4\x8A\xA8V\x9A\xAA\xAB\xAF\xC3&.\xED[\x04\xC5e\x7F\x08\xBE\x8Ar\xA7\xB0\x99F\xF7\x11\xE5\xD6\x96\x8CIm+w\x1C\xFDuU\x14\x0F!x\xAC\xE8MPy\xC3\x19!2\xA0\xED\xC0}!Rw\x14\x8E\x1B\xC4\xE1\xA0\xAF+\xADKk\xC5\xE0\x5Cs\x9C\xBD\xCB" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
84.21.172.128 - - [28/Nov/2022:03:24:05 +0000] "POST /boaform/admin/formLogin HTTP/1.1" 405 150 "http://147.182.131.129:80/admin/login.asp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0" "-"
84.21.172.128 - - [28/Nov/2022:03:24:05 +0000] "" 400 0 "-" "-" "-"
192.241.211.240 - - [28/Nov/2022:03:35:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x" "-"
66.240.205.34 - - [28/Nov/2022:03:47:27 +0000] "145.ll|'|'|SGFjS2VkX0Q0OTkwNjI3|'|'|WIN-JNAPIER0859|'|'|JNapier|'|'|19-02-01|'|'||'|'|Win 7 Professional SP1 x64|'|'|No|'|'|0.7d|'|'|..|'|'|AA==|'|'|112.inf|'|'|SGFjS2VkDQoxOTIuMTY4LjkyLjIyMjo1NTUyDQpEZXNrdG9wDQpjbGllbnRhLmV4ZQ0KRmFsc2UNCkZhbHNlDQpUcnVlDQpGYWxzZQ==12.act|'|'|AA==" 400 150 "-" "-" "-"
```

Some of these request also appear in Django logs

```bash
Not Found: /portal/redlion
Not Found: /portal/redlion
Not Found: /admin.php
Not Found: /user/15751/
Not Found: /user/15761
Not Found: //script/.env
Not Found: //script/.env
Not Found: //admin-app/.env
Not Found: //admin-app/.env
Not Found: /portal/redlion
Not Found: /administrator/db/index.php
Not Found: /administratorindex.php
Not Found: /administrator/db/index.php
Not Found: /administrator/phpMyAdmin/index.php
Not Found: /administrator/db/index.php
Not Found: /administratorindex.php
Not Found: /administrator/web/index.php
Not Found: /administrator/PMA/index.php
Not Found: /administrator/db/index.php
Not Found: /administrator/db/index.php
Not Found: /administrator/db/index.php
Not Found: /admin/login.asp
Not Found: /portal/redlion
```

The Nginx works on the IP ADDR without a domain

***nginx.conf***

```
upstream websocket {
    server asgiserver:9000;
}

error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log  warn;


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xx;
    server_tokens off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log  warn;


    client_max_body_size 100M;
    client_body_timeout 300s;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;


   location ~ /.well-known {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }



    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /script {
       try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }

    location /auth {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }

    location /user {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }
    
    location /portal {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }

    location /admin {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }
    
 

    location @proxy_api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass  http://backend:8000;
    }

    location /django_static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/backend/server/django_static/;
    }

    location  /media {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/backend/server/media;
    }
    
    location @proxy_websocket {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        # proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
        resolver 10.108.0.2;
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_connect_timeout 7d;
        proxy_send_timeout 7d;
        proxy_read_timeout 7d;
        proxy_buffers 512 256M;
        proxy_buffer_size 256M;
    }

   
}
```

Could the server be hacked? Especially since the rate of Ram consumption increased exaggeratedly

Comment: someone trying to access admin portal as he think this website is on php. So he/she may be trying to access admin page for hacking purpose.

Comment: These are are a combination of: 1) Automatic scripts from companies all over the world scraping all IP-addresses. 2) Hackers and Script-kiddies
Best to ignore those and don't proxy them to other containers (your Django) but let the Nginx Containr handle them (aka: Ignore)

Comment: @BertC How can I ignore them in Nginx, it's hard to define a location for each endpoint in the log above

Answer (score 0):

In reaction to the last comment in the question:
"How can I ignore them in Nginx, it's hard to define a location for each endpoint in the log above"

My comment was make under the impression that you have 1 container running Nginx and another one running Django.
The Django container might have a separate (sub)domainname. Then Nginx will only pass on requests to Django is the domainname matches, not only the IP.
In your case you have the server listening to the IP address, which gives a match for all kinds of garbage based on the IP.